# How can I extract data from unbalanced tables in pdf using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdftotext

I need to extract data from tables (like below) in PDF using Python. First, I want to have all left-side data on a page then the right-side data. I have tried to use `text.split('\n')` and `re.split(r'\s{3,}')`, but nothing works.
[image]

[Link of the pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K-6EcFv5qG-cAypZRf8h2toQ5N4m6gJd/view?usp=sharing)

```
import re
import pdfplumber

pdf = 'Example.pdf'

lines = []
with pdfplumber.open(pdf) as pdf:
pages = pdf.pages
for page in pages:
    text = page.extract_text()
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        nline = text.split(r'\s{3,}')
        print(nline)
```

First, I want to have a list like the following:

```
Text:    
1110 Crop production
1111A0 Oilseed farming 11111-2
1111B0 Grain farming 11113-6, 11119
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
311520 Ice cream and frozen dessert manufacturing 311520
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these libraries to extract text from pdf.

1. PyPDF2
2. PDFMiner

Illustration to easily use these libraries is given in this link. [1](https://towardsdatascience.com/pdf-text-extraction-in-python-5b6ab9e92dd)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: PyPDF2 and PDFMiner don't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use tabula-py or camelot?
Recent, I used those packages and parse to pandas dataframe from pdf.

Here are the sites.

https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: `tabula-py` did not work. And not able to get `camelot-py` working.